# Is display_errors = stderr valid?

Tags: php

It's been a while since I have done PHP but the behaviour I observe regarding error display in stdout and stderr is not what is [documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors), so I wonder if there is a problem with my config or if the doc is simply out of date.

What I observe is that `display_errors = stderr` does not send errors to stderr instead of stdout. It results in `display_errors` being "On" and in errors still being sent to stdout.

I am also confused by the fact that the setting `display_errors` seems to be a boolean when you look at phpinfo (either "On" or "Off") but the documentation directs you to using a string value, which is confusing.

The behaviour that I am after is:

- I should not see errors/warnings mixed with the output of a script (say a JSON or XML file in a HTTP response body — I don't mean what is displayed in the terminal which mixes stderr and stdout by design)
- I should see errors/warnings when I filter the logs with `docker logs [my container] -f 1>/dev/null` (which redirects stdout to /dev/null, leaving only stderr)

My config is a docker image I extended from [php:8-apache](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/), so I guess you could call it a "fresh install" of something officially supported.

I initially tried setting up my Dockerfile as follows, adding two lines at the end of php.ini:

```
FROM php:8-apache

# Pick php.ini variant
RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

# Redirect errors to stderr
RUN echo "display_errors = stderr" >> "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
RUN echo "log_errors = 1" >> "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
...
```

But it did not behave as expected. I could still see warnings and errors in the output (defined above). What did work was setting `"display_errors = 0"` instead of `"display_errors = stderr"`. This is not what the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) says.

With `display_errors` set to `0` in php.ini I tried overriding the value at runtime with `ini_set('display_errors', 'stderr')` and then doing `phpinfo()` and I could verify that the "master value" is `Off` (expected) when the "local value" is `On` (not expected): doing `ini_set('display_errors', 'stderr')` actually turned `display_errors` back on, which again is not what the documentation suggests.

I don't have any fancy configuration. `php --ini` returns the following:

```bash
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
```

docker-php-ext-sodium.ini only contains `extension=sodium`.

Comment: `stderr` and `stdout` are normally both connected to the terminal, so when you use `displahy_errors = stdout` you see the errors in the output.

Comment: In a terminal, unless you redirect stderr to a file (or /dev/null) you'll see it anyway.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify. I am aware the terminal is connected to both streams, it is not the problem. I care about stdout not containing errors and warnings. I achieved it through a mean which is not documented and the recommended way did not work for me.

Comment: "I am also confused by the fact that the setting display_errors seems to be a boolean...but the documentation directs you to using a string value" - I think this is just a historical artifact. You can even [instruct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php) one of the internal parsers to give you a raw string or attempt to parse as a native time.